# Pygame--pygame can't run a pingpong collision game

Tags: python, pygame

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
import sys


class MyBallClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, speed, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
        self.speed = speed

    def move(self):
        global points, score_text
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > screen.get_width():
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]

        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
            points += 1
            score_text = font.render(str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))


class MyPaddleClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location=[0, 0]):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        image_surface = pygame.surface.Surface([100, 20])  
        image_surface.fill([0, 0, 0])  
        self.image = image_surface.convert()   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()   
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ball_speed = [3, 4]
myball = MyBallClass("E:\\python file\\blackball.jpg", ball_speed, [50, 50])
ballgroup = pygame.sprite.Group(myball)
paddle = MyPaddleClass([270, 400])
lives = 3
points = 0

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
score_text = font.render(str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
textpos = [10, 10]
done = False

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            paddle.rect.centerx = event.pos[0]

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(paddle, ballgroup, False):
        myball.speed[1] = -myball.speed[1]
    myball.move()
    if not done:
        screen.blit(myball.image, myball.rect)
        screen.blit(paddle.image, paddle.rect)
        screen.blit(score_text, textpos)
        for i in range(lives):
            width = screen.get_width()
            screen.blit(myball.image, [width - 40 * i, 20])
        pygame.display.flip()
    if myball.rect.top <= screen.get_rect().bottom:
        #  In get_rect(), you cannot leave out brackets
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            final_text1 = "Game over!"
            final_text2 = 'your final score is' + str(points)
            ft1_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 70)
            ft2_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
            ft1_surface = font.render(final_text1, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            ft2_surface = font.render(final_text2, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(ft1_surface, [screen.get_width() / 2, 100])
            screen.blit(ft2_surface, [screen.get_width() / 2, 200])
            pygame.display.flip()
            done = True
        else:
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            myball.rect.topleft = [50, 50]
        frame_rate = clock.get_fps()
        print(frame_rate)
```

Here is the pygame window picture of my code:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFyBJ.jpg)

Every time I run it, I don't have the time to control the paddle, then it shows game is over. I have been searching for a long time but can't find out why. It seems like the blackball is moving so fast that the game is over in about one second. But I already set the speed to a reasonable range, I am so confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: first time you lost a life, you set `done` and never set it to false. You have to improve your state machine a little bit. Also print values of `myball.rect.top` and `screen.get_rect().bottom` in your while loop, you may be surprised.

Comment: In my `if lives == 0` statement, I have set the done to True. And where should I add the code for printing values of `myball.rect.top` and `screen.get_rect().bottom` in my while loop?

Comment: print them anywhere. just after while is OK

Comment: You mean like this `while 1: print myball.rect.top, print screen.get_rect.bottom` or print them outside the loop. I have tried both, and neither of them worked.

Comment: neither of them worked??? try `print (myball.rect.top, screen.get_rect.bottom)`.

Comment: I have tried `print (myball.rect.top, screen.get_rect.bottom)` in and outside the `while 1` loop, it only print more `(50, 480) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could rebuild your game, and fixed the problem.

Try inverse condition here

```
if myball.rect.top >= screen.get_rect().bottom:
```

and it works fine: I can hit the ball with the bat, make it bounce, ...

I don't know why it took me so long ot figure it out: you lose the game if ball goes off the screen by the bottom. For that, top y must be greater than the bottom of the window (computer screen coordinates are 0,0 from upper left)